# Varignon's Parallelogram Area For "Square" Bow-tie

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry

[This](http://dynamicmathematicslearning.com/crossed-quad-area.pdf) paper suggests that via [Varignon's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Varignon%27s_theorem) the area of an arbitrary quadrilateral is twice that of the parallelogram created by the mid points of the edges of the quadrilateral. However, if we take a bowtie s.t. (x, y) = (0, 0), (1, 1), (0, 1), (1, 0), then the area of the parallelogram created by the mid points is zero whilst the area of the bowtie is a half. Have I missed something?

Comment: A bowtie is neither convex nor concave. From wiki "... If the quadrilateral is `convex or concave` (not complex), then the area of the parallelogram is half the area of the quadrilateral."

Comment: Then the first paper is misleading? Is there a formula for the area of a complex quadrilateral?

Comment: If you go on reading that paper, you'll realise that the area of a bowtie is zero.

Comment: ooohh because of the orientation of the areas! Ah, thanks! Got it!